# how to get rows that repeated X times or more?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains some data. i have a 'username' field in my table that stores users username.

in this table there is possible that a user have many records.

now, how can i get the users that their username repeated more than X times? (50 time or more for example?)
and after that i want to delete rows for each user that i get in previous step but i need to keep first X rows and i need to delete all rows after row X for each user.

how can i do this with mysql and php?

---

update: i solve my problem with this:

```
SELECT username, count(*) as numRecords
FROM table
GROUP BY username
```

Comment: By writing the code to do so :) Look up some tutorials on how to interact with a database through php.

Comment: @Epodax i have do many queries but i cant do this. i searched many websits and questions but i dont get answer... why u point - to me??

Comment: SO doesn't provide tutorials or guides on how to do things, if you included some code of a attempt to achieve your desired functionality but was stuck / ran into errors it would be a different story. But as I understand your question right now, then it's to me off-topic / too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take a number of steps to achive..

Start by building a query to count the number of records for each user

```
SELECT username, count(*) as numRecords
FROM table
GROUP BY username
```

Then add:

```
HAVING numRecords > 5
```

to narrow down to usernames with more than 5 records..

Loop through the records from the query above..

```
foreach($results as $result){

    // Query db using `username` to get the 'record to keep'
    "SELECT * FROM table 
     WHERE username = $result['username']
     ORDER BY someUniqueID
     LIMIT 1"

    __Execute the query__

    __Store the record ID to keep__

   // Delete records (except the one to keep)
   "DELETE FROM table
    WHERE username = $result['username']
    AND someUniqueID != $someUniqueID"

    __Execute the query__

}
```

Comment: thanks bro can u explain for delete query too? and if u give me php code for this ill be very happy!

Comment: Do you have anything unique in the rows that can be used to select one..?  InsertDate for axample..?

Comment: thanks but select query not working and when i use mysql_num_rows after do query, not thing returned!

Comment: this is my code:       $do_uq = mysql_db_query("SELECT username, count(*) as numRecords
FROM ofRoster
GROUP BY username HAVING numRecords > 5", $dbconn);
 $numofcu = mysql_num_rows($do_uq);
 echo $numofcu . "<br><hr>";

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `username`, COUNT(`username`) AS `numRecords`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `username`
HAVING `numRecords` > 'someNumber'
```

Comment: i tried ur code but when i fetch the resault no thing happens